# Broaden off-topic migration flags

Tags: discussion, migration

When was the last time the migration selection was updated ?
It's lacking programmers, code review, software rec and user experience SE.
And I'm not a huge reviewer, but I never had to migrate to tex or stats...

[image: migration]

Answer (score 3):

SO has a *terrible* history of migrations to Programmers.  Way, way too many SO users seem to think it's just a place to dump all bad questions.  Very few seem to actually understand what's on topic there.  Also note that there have only been 22 migrations to Programmers in the past 90 days (putting it in 9th place).

Code Review and Software Recommendations are in beta, and are thus ineligible as migration targets.  CR actually has a lot of migrations, so it'll likely be *considered* as a migration target when it leaves beta; but it may or may not make it based on a number of factors that will need to be considered at that time.  As for SR, it has a whopping 1 migration in the past 90 days; it's clearly nowhere near meriting a slot.

As for UX, it literally has **zero** migrations from SO in the past 90 days.  Obviously it's not a frequent migration target.

As for the items on the list not being frequent migration targets, stats is the site with the single most migrations in the past 90 days, with 137 migrations.  Tex is 7th at the moment, with one of the items above it being an inelligible migration target, and the other being GIS with 32 migrations (to Tex's 30).  We'd need to see GIS surpassing Tex regularly over an extended period of time to merit it bumping it off of the list.

Comment: Ok ! I understand the beta status and programmers.se problem. Thanks!

Comment: The examples in this Q & A may be not very good, but the concept is still very true -- I see a LOT of topics on SO that should be moved to `gamedev` (as well as various other SE forums) but the fact that SE has what 50+ forums and only 5 migration links, it's not great. The fact that some migrations are not used correctly or that are a `dumping ground` is second to the fact that SO is the biggest and most popular SE site and so is a first port of call for an awful lot of people whose questions can be better answered / researched on more specific SE sites

Comment: @Martin No, it's *not* second to that.  We don't *want* the most of those questions migrated, because the most of them aren't good questions to migrate.  Having an easier migration path would mean that those sites would simply get flooded with bad and/or inappropriate questions migrated over from SO by people that don't understand the site, it's scope, it's quality standards, etc. and often moving more quesitons than these smaller sites have the users to properly moderate.

Comment: Make it difficult to transfer valid and useful questions because *some* questions may not be up to standard and will apparently not be weeded out by other options on the **close** portal? While I can see your point of view in general, I disagree with your assertion. If SO doesn't move out things that are not SO related and instead valid `gamedev` questions get answered and upvoted by SO users then this means that gamedev SE gets less traffic and less users, and SO gets more, as more and more [beginner] game developers will google questions and find answers in SO rather than on gamedev.SE

Comment: There's two factors here; **1)** the validity/quality of the question itself and **2)** the validity / quality of the reviewer wanting to move this question. Bad questions don't belong on *any* SE site, be it SO or gamedev or any other. I think you're getting so worried about point 1, that you're forgetting that if SO doesn't distribute it's content to other related sites, it will never [does not] remain focused on its primary purpose while at the same time collecting traffic / users / advise providers from other SE sites

Comment: @Martin Making it difficult to transfer questions because *the vast majority* of questions migrated are bad questions (which we know, because it's been demonstrated time and again that SO users are bad at determining what should be migrated to other sites), and where the target site simply won't have the means to properly handle those quesitons, all so that the *very few* good questions that should be migrated take only the tiniest bit less effort?  When this *hasn't* been done, and easy migration paths have existed, it's completely tanked other sites, causing serious problems for *years*.

Comment: @Servy if there's a track record of SO bad decision making then yeah, fair enough, from the way you angle your words it sounds endemic that SO users are poor decision makers `:-/`

Comment: @Martin I mean it's not particularly reasonable to expect most SO users to know what types of questions are appropriate for sites they aren't active on, but yes, there is lots of evidence that they're *really* bad at migrations, even more so than you'd expect given that they are out of their area of expertise.

Comment: I think many would say that this is [as much as can be expected](http://img.pandawhale.com/post-44331-Everything-happens-for-a-reaso-wPdB.jpeg)